# .htaccess: Redirect all pages except one

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to setup my `.htaccess` file to redirect from `oldsite.com` to `newsite.com`, with just one exception: If the user visits `http://oldsite.com/cal` then I want it to display the `cal.html` file in the root directory.

Here's the current `.htaccess` file that I've got (which doesn't work):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# this page can be served .. (not working)
RewriteRule /cal http://oldsite.com/cal.htm [L,NC]

# .. but rewrite everything else (this works fine)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://newsite.com/$1     [R=301,L,NC]
```

What do I mean by *it doesn't work*? Well, it just redirects `http://oldsite.com/cal` to `http://newsite.com/cal` instead of displaying `http://oldsite.com/cal.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cal/? cal.htm [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Notes

- if `oldsite` and `newsite` live on different servers, you don't even need the RewriteCond.
- you could also invert the order of the rules, in which case the main rule would be `RewriteRule ^(?!cal/?$) http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]`

Comment: Works, thanks .. waiting for 4 minutes to pass. That's interesting .. Why do I not need the RewriteCond if they're on different servers (they are)?

Comment: The RewriteCond is just a filter so the rule only fires in certain conditions... If the host is always `oldsite`, then there is no need to test for that condition.

Comment: Thanks, I get by with RegEx but I can't get my head around the `%{...}` in Apache. If you've got a good reference that'd be great..

Comment: There are many tuts but none as useful as the documentation. If you google you'll probably land on the wrong page, IMO [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) is the best gateway into the mod-rewrite doc.